# A matching distance

Tags: metric-spaces

Consider $\sigma,\sigma' \in \{1,\dots,p\}^n$, and let
$$
 d(\sigma,\sigma') = \min_{\pi \in S_p} \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{ \pi(\sigma_i) \neq \sigma'_i \}}
$$
where $S_p$ is the symmetric group on $\{1,\dots,p\}$ (the set of permutations of that set). Is $d$ a valid metric? In particular, does the triangle inequality hold?

EDIT: I should have stated the question as this: Is this a valid pseudo-metric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a metric, since the distance is $0$ for vectors that are permutations of each other.

[*Edit:*]

However, it's a pseudometric which vanishes if and only if ignoring the order of the vectors yields the same multiset. Thus the [metric identification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space#Metric_identification) of this pseudometric considers vectors equivalent if they correspond to the same multiset, and it induces a metric on the set of multisets of $n$ out of $p$ items.

Clearly $d(\sigma,\sigma)=0$ and $d(\sigma,\sigma')=d(\sigma',\sigma)$, so we only have to check the triangle inequality to show that this is indeed a pseudometric on the vectors and a metric on the multisets. But the triangle inequality is fulfilled since for three vectors $a,b,c\in\{1,\dotsc,p\}^n$ we can compose the minimizing permutations for $d(a,b)$ and $d(b,c)$ to obtain a permutation that is a witness for the triangle inequality, since the number of mismatches left by the composition is at most the sum of the numbers of mismatches left by the individual permutations.

Comment: Thanks. That is fine, my main concern is the triangle inequality. I have edited the question.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on the last sentence you wrote (this part: "since the number of mismatches left...")? Is that supposed to be obvious?

Comment: By the way, do you know if this distance or a variant of it has a name?

Comment: @passerby51: The minimizing permutation for $d(a,b)$ moves as many elements of $a$ as possible such that they end up matching elements in $b$. Except for the factor $1/n$, your (pseudo)metric counts the number of mismatches between $b$ and the permuted version of $a$. If you now apply the minimizing permutation for $d(b,c)$ to the permuted version of $a$, any elements that had been matched up with $b$ are now matched up with $c$, unless they're among the elements that this second permutation fails to match when permuting $b$ to match $c$.

Comment: @passerby51: Regarding a name for the metric, I don't know one; you might call it the multiset metric, or you could check [this book](http://books.google.de/books?id=I-PQH8gcOjUC&lpg=PA147&ots=5aZ057rvID&dq=multiset%20metric&hl=de&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=multiset%20metric&f=false), which amazingly consists of definitions and names of various metrics filling $400$ pages.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the insightful comment and the wonderful link.